# comparing file names while iterating through a directory

Tags: java, file-io

I need to compare file names with different extension to look for files with same names. I am not concerned with the extension. I am using SimpleFileVisitor method visitFile() to go through the files. I am just taking the root directory name or the directory name and using walkFileTree() to get the files,so I am not aware of the number of files.The process has to be a background process.I have thought to use thread to walk through the files and match them but not getting how to implement it. So how do I add the comparing scenario?? My code for getting the filenames is:-

```
package trigger;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes;

public class ProcessFilePath extends SimpleFileVisitor<Path>{

        String [] str;
        String name;

        @Override 
        public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path aFile, BasicFileAttributes aAttrs) throws IOException 

        {
            str= aFile.toFile().getName().split("\\.");
             name=str[0];
             System.out.println("filename : " + name);
             return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;

        }



    }
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the File Name from path.

```
File f = new File("C:\\Hello\\AnotherFolder\\The File Name.PDF");
System.out.println(f.getName());
```

Use to remove file extension

```
str.substring(0, str.lastIndexOf('.'));
```

Compare the filenames.

```
// These two have the same value
new String("test").equals("test") ==> true 

// ... but they are not the same object
new String("test") == "test" ==> false 

// ... neither are these
new String("test") == new String("test") ==> false 

// ... but these are because literals are interned by 
// the compiler and thus refer to the same object
"test" == "test" ==> true 

// concatenation of string literals happens at compile time resulting in same objects
"test" == "te" + "st"  ==> true

// but .substring() is invoked at runtime, generating distinct objects
"test" == "!test".substring(1) ==> false
```

Comment: @user2553442...actually i am just taking the root directory name or the directory name and then walking through it using walkFileTree(). I don't know what can be the exact number of files i have to match. So your answer seems a bit confusing.

Comment: You are trying to match the files from different directories? Store the filenames in String array and compare the file names.

Comment: @user2553442...please go through the question again. I have made some edits.

Comment: While walkFileTree() you can compare the current file name with other file names.

Comment: @usre2553442....please be clear to what you are saying. your comment is confusing and not clear.

Comment: Store all the filenames from directory in string array and compare the  files it will seems easy for you.

Comment: that would limit the continuity of my process as it has to be a background process.